# How to get number from for-loop to make a new array

Tags: java

First,I random some number and show what random number I get.

```
System.out.print("Numbers : ");
randomInts(num, min, max); 
int a[] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < randomInts(num, min, max).length; i++) {
        int s = randomInts(num, min, max)[i];
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }

public static int[] randomInts(int num,int start,int end) {
    Random random1 = new Random();  
    return random1.ints(num, start, end).toArray();
}
```

How can I add variable s in int a[]  because I would like to bring int a[] to do next step. For example  get sum from number in a[]

for output:

```
Number : 1 2
Array int a[] : [1,2]
sum : 3
```

Comment: I've updated my answer showing how to print the array as `Array int a[] : [1,2]`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add variable s in int a[]

You just have to assign "s" to "a" at position "i". For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomInts(num, min, max).length; i++) {
    int s = randomInts(num, min, max)[i];
    System.out.print(s + " ");
    a[i] = s; // <-- Here you assign s to the array at position i
}
```

Later, you can iterate over the array "a" to sum the elements or whatever.

---

## Update

In order to print the elements of an array you can use the utility `Arrays` class:

```
System.out.println("Array int a[]: " + Arrays.toString(a));
```

Then for an array with elements `[1, 2]` it gets printed out `Array int a[]: [1, 2]`